# Loop to change positive or negative based on another cell text

Tags: excel, vba, return-value

One column has positive or negative numbers or "incomplete". Another column, same row has "yes" or "no". All matching "yes" numbers should be negative and all matching "no" numbers should be positive.

I was able to skip "incomplete" and change the values, but I change all values.
If the "yes" number is already negative it is changed to positive.
I read other posts, modified my code and now I'm getting a "type mismatch".

```
Sub posneg()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pn As Range

    Set pn = rawday.Range(rawday.Range("A4"). _
    Offset(0, 42), rawday.Range("A4").Offset(0, 42).End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In pn
        If cell = "Incomplete" Then cell = ""

        ElseIf cell = "Yes" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -30) = Abs(cell.Offset(0, -30)) * -1
            cell.Offset(0, -30).Value = Abs(cell.Offset(0, -30)) * -1
        ElseIf cell = "No" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -30) = Abs(cell.Offset(0, -30)) * 1
            cell.Offset(0, -30).Value = Abs(cell.Offset(0, -30)) * 1
        End If       
    Next

End Sub
```

I expect all matching "Yes" values to be negative and all matching "No" values to be positive.
Thank you!

My brain was totally clouded! I removed *-1 from the "No"'s and the values remained positive.

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: `For Each cell in pn` is relying on the default property of whatever you are looping through. Typically for a cell item that is value or similar, but its best to be specific, so inside the loop update your cell comparisons from `cell = "text"` to 'cell.value = "text"` as needed.

Comment: We can only guess without more input, but my guess is that you have text in the cells you are trying to change, which would cause the issue.  Maybe the numbers are stored as numbers?

Comment: I am getting an error on this line `cell.Offset(0, -30) = Abs(cell.Offset(0, -30)) * -1`  I changed `cell="text"` to `cell.value = "text"` and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Scott, I'm not sure what you mean, but the cells are formatted as general.

Comment: If you have text in any of the cells, trying to call `Abs` on it will fail.

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked a column header. I swapped the looped cells with the comparisons. I no longer get the error message, but I'm unsure how to have the related "Yes" cells that are negative not change to positive. `If cell.Offset(0, 30) = "Incomplete" Then
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 30) = "Yes" Then
                cell.Value = cell.Value * -1
             ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 30) = "No" Then
               cell.Value = Abs(cell.Value) * 1
           End If
     Next`